# GitHub API occassionaly returns 'Bad credentials' despite rate limit not being exceeded

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, github-api

I have a Jenkins pipeline, which makes a number of requests to the GitHub API.

While 99% of the requests are successful, GitHub API occassionaly returns this response:

```
{
  "message": "Bad credentials",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest"
}
```

I was suspecting it to be an exceeded rate limit, so I guarded against this by fetching and printing out the rate limits before each GitHub API request:

```
curl -s -u <username:password> https://api.github.com/rate_limit
```

It shows that everytime I get a 'Bad credentials' response, the remaining rate limits fetched right before were high.

I have tried having the pipeline retry a number of times with a 15 second delay between retries. Sometimes this works and the pipeline is able to proceed, while other times it gets 'Bad credentials' in all the retries.

I'm not sure what to make of this. Any suggestions?

Thanks